# How could I add text to an image using PIL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I've seen many questions and answers here, but they're not for Python. I'm trying to make a meme generator, and I have a folder full of emme templates. I want to make the user get a meme template, view it then add text. Here is my code so far:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("Two-Buttons.jpg")
im.show()
```

Yeah, I know it's not much but I need help with getting user input on a certain part of the text.

Comment: Going off of what @martineau said, a good habit to develop is the ability to read documentation. While it may seem daunting at first, consistently reading documentation will allow you to solve problems similar to this one.

Answer (score 1):

First, you would need to import the necessary objects to draw on images from the `PIL` library:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
```

Then, you instantiate the `ImageDraw` class:

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
```

Then you can simply do the following to draw on the *original* image `im`:

```
text = 'Insert meme here'
font_type = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 18)  # 18 -> font size
draw.text((100, 100), text, (255, 255, 0), font=font_type)  # "draw.text(LOCATION, TEXT, COLOR, FONT_TYPE)"
im.show()
```